# Getting String from Spinner, and using it on conditional statements

Tags: android, datetime, spinner, conditional-statements, eclipse-adt

I have this program that will change the hours and minutes of the values I get from Calendar.

So I'm changing only the hour, I'm doing a Timezone thing here. So, what I do is I make an array of the TimeZones at Strings.xml and put it on a spinner. And then, when I change the item on the spinner, I set the text of a textview to the selected value on the spinner.

I can do it up to here.

My problem lies in the conditional statements. I have a button that gets the text in the TextView and I will use that in my If statements. This is my Syntax.

This gets me the values from the Spinner to the TextView.

```
    Spinner TimezoneSelect = (Spinner)findViewById (R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.timzones, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    TimezoneSelect.setAdapter(adapter);
    //final String SelectedTimeZone = TimezoneSelect.getSelectedItem().toString();
    TimezoneSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimeZoneStatus = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            TimeZoneDisplay.setText(TimeZoneStatus);
```

And this is the faulty If statement.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int newhour;
        String TimeZoneNow = TimeZoneStatus.trim().toString();
        String Jakarta = "UTC+7:00 (Jakarta)";
        if  ((TimeZoneNow == "UTC+7:00(Jakarta)") || (TimeZoneNow == Jakarta)) 
        //^lol desperate code
        {
            newhour = hour - 1;
            TimeText.setText(newhour + ":" + minutes);
        }

    }

   });
```

Help! :c

Comment: [Comparing Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
 if  ((TimeZoneNow .equalsIgnoreCase(Jakarta)) 
    //^lol desperate code
    {
        newhour = hour - 1;
        TimeText.setText(newhour + ":" + minutes);
    }
```

Comment: This what I used, but I'm sure all the .equals ones are right. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
if(TimeZoneNow.equals(Jakarta)
```

used `.equals()` method for string comparison

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your case replace `==` with `eqauls()`.

Explanation:

`==` operator is used to compare reference.

`equals()` is used to compare content.